# Python | If file contain more than X lines, exit and print message

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to create error handler in python, python will check the file and if the file contains more than 95000 lines, it will stop and print an error message.

Is it an easy way to make this?

This is solution I found:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
```

And then something like, if i > 95000 print 'Error'

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: Do you really need a solution which works in both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x]?

Comment: @tripleee Ideally this is what I'm looking for

Comment: What's wrong with the code you found? Just replace the `pass` with  `if i > 95000: raise ValueError('File is too big')` inside the loop.

Comment: @tripleee as well I found - num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt')) , I'm looking for and appropriate way of error handler , (I'm just new to this... and maybe this is a way of using any kind of exceptions and so on to handle this issues) ...??

Comment: Depending on why exactly you want this, raising an exception is probably the most pythonic. If you need the calling program not to fail, catch the error with `try`/`except`

Comment: @tripleee I'm getting data from API which limited to 100 000 record per request (usually data will be on average 50-70k) ,  so to avoid any data missing... need try catch ,error handler that if it pass the limit I will be notified by email..  sorry for bad question, but it was more about... What is the best way to handle this error (because I thought that , by using hard coded part.. is not looking really pythonic, "proffectionally"..)...

Comment: If my obvious solution is not acceptable, please [edit] your question to clarify what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this simple approach:

```
with open(<your_file>, 'r') as abc:
    lines = [i for i in abc.readlines() if len(i)>1]
    if len(lines) >95000:
        raise StopIteration("File too big!")
```

Comment: This is wasteful in that it reads the entire file into memory before deciding. Reading 10 million lines when you know after 100,000 that they are too many will needlessly allocate a lot of memory for data you will never use, probably resulting in swapping and degraded overall performance on many servers.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was a good one:

```
def get_bounded_num_lines(k, infile):
    """Returns min(K, number of lines in infile).

    Max running time is proportional to K rather than total file length,
    similar to /usr/bin/head -K.
    """
    try:
        for i in range(k + 1):
            next(infile)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    infile.close()
    return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    k, fspec = 95000, '/tmp/foo.txt'
    if get_bounded_num_lines(k, open(fspec)) >= k:
        raise ValueError('File is too big')
```

This avoids wasting lots of time reading every single line of a multi-terabyte file before signaling an error.

If you don't need a completely accurate result and your files have predictable contents, then read the head of the file, the first 100 lines or so, add up their length, and compute `avg_line_length = total_head_length / 100`. Armed with that and with `file_length = os.path.getsize(fspec)`, you'd be able to *very* quickly compute `estimated_num_lines = int(file_length / avg_line_length)` and compare to that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no blank lines in the file, you can use the `linecache` library, which provides the content of a line directly. Try this one:

```
file_path="path_to_file"  
line_content=linecache.getline(file_path,95000)
if line_content:
   print "Lines goes beyond limit error"
```

More details at https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html

Comment: Nice alternative solution, though I have also upvoted the other answer.